Android app uninstall doesn't reset GDPR consent on my device as expected
I use Admob to collect consent for GDPR compliance in my Android apps. Before testing a new release on my device, I always uninstall the old version so that the consent gets reset, allowing me to verify that the consent form is shown on the first run.
However, for one of my apps, uninstalling doesn't reset the consent. If I build the app with a different (random) package name, everything works as expected: the consent form is shown on the first run, and uninstalling the app resets the consent.
When I build and run the app with the real package name, in the adb logcat, I see the message: GoogleMobileAds.Ump.Android.ConsentFormClient:onConsentFormDismissed. It seems like my device "remembers" that particular package name and never asks for consent. How is this even possible?
UPDATE: The app is now live on the Play Store, and the GDPR consent is reset every time I uninstall it, as expected. So, the issue described was present only when installing via USB.

If local files are really deleted upon app deletion (there is an option to keep the user data files) then the only way would be server side identification. The only identifier that should be allowed to be used for such purpose is the "Advertising ID" which can be reset  in Settings -> Privacy > Ads. What happens if you uninstall the app reset the Advertising ID and then reinstall it without changing the packagename?

Thanks, I have tried resetting the Adverting ID, but it has no effect on this issue.

When your app is re-installed, the configuration files are restored by the operating system itself. You have to disable that behavior in the manifest of your app in the application tag. Check here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element
the subtags
android:allowBackup
android:dataExtractionRules
android:fullBackupContent
android:fullBackupOnly

For GDPR consent, the settings are stored in "sharedpref", so you may want to exclude only that files

Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that this behavior is due to Android Auto Backup. However, if this were true, then it would be the normal behavior. On the contrary, this issue occurs only with a certain device and a certain bundle ID. Excluding this particular case, in my experience, uninstalling the app always resets GDPR consent.

Raffaè leggi qua: https://developer.android.com/identity/data/autobackup#RestoreSchedule on the first verse. Yes uninstalling the app then the consent is reset, but when you reinstall it, then settings (and shared preferences too) are restored

Non ho capito che cosa è il tuo "Bundle ID"

Ho scritto Bundle ID ma intendevo dire "Package name" https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9972781?hl=en cioè l'identificativo univoco dell'app. Il Bundle ID è stessa cosa, ma nel mondo Apple. Ho editato la domanda per correggere l'errore, grazie.

English translation of my previous comment:
I wrote Bundle ID but I meant to say 'Package name' support.google.com/admob/answer/9972781?hl=en, which refers to the unique identifier of the app. The Bundle ID is the same thing, but in the Apple world. I have edited the question to correct the mistake, thanks.

Regarding the article you linked, it doesn’t explicitly mention GDPR consent. In my experience (I have several published apps), GDPR consent is reset upon uninstall, and now that this particular app is live on the Play Store, this is what happens. So the issue was present only when installing via USB. I have updated my question to clarify this.

this happens on a real phone? maybe you have a particular setting on your phone. Try on a fresh installation of an emulator image. In addition, when you install via usb your app on your phone, read carefully the logcat, there is something that concerns the restoration on configuration/settings
